# People on different time streams

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, pulp

I remember a story about how people stopped moving. They buried them. Then people started disappearing. Turns out, people were moving into different time streams. The people not moving were just moving really slow, and the people disappearing were moving super fast. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you remember any more details? As it stands, this question runs the risk of being closed as too broad.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Joel! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [story-ID guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question, so that it will be easier for others to find the book that you are searching for.

Comment: @Politank-Z How is it too broad? You mean you know several stories that match the description? Could you please name some of them?

Comment: @user14111 I can not. It is vaguely familiar, though, and also vague.

Answer (score 7):

You may be thinking of ["Co-existence"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?92551) (also known as ["The River of Time")](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?92551), a story by David Brin, which first appeared in *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine* (May 1982), and which appears in Brin's collection *[The River of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_River_of_Time)* (1986).  It deals with how people perceive one another as they transition between different time rates, and it mentions some early unfortunates who were prematurely declared dead.

This question may be a duplicate of [Story-identification, short story with time dilation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161524/story-identification-short-story-with-time-dilation), which has this story as a proposed answer.